# Hibernate doesn't see data in the database

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA (2.5.2) with Oracle DB and enabled auditing-jpa feature and Azure AD security (an example of configuration https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa)

I observe strange behavior - I run 2 instance of my app

When I created a one row from the instance1  the instance2 of my app doesn't see data created by instance1. Instance1 of course can get created data. This same behavior for each query which I defined in the app.

When I query data directly from DB (DBeaver) I see all data.

Looks like each instance works in "isolated mode" :/

Any suggestion?

Comment: Without code and limited information, it is hard to suggest...

Comment: this is weird tho, are the apps running in your local environment or on the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Instance1 in running on the cloud with timezone UTC and instane2 is running locally with timezone Europ/Copenhagen. Queries are include timestamp fields so this was mismatched